# decrease a counter when a key is pressed (ANDROID)

Tags: java, android

i have to decrease a counter When a char is written , but my code is decreasing two chars Instead of one but Only When delete key is pressed , but if 
if I press another key does not work

```
private Button send;
private TextView max;
private TextView msg;
int limit=140;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     max = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.max);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);

    msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);
    msg.setOnKeyListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
}
@Override
public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    max.setText(String.valueOf(limit--));
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey i have found the answer,

first of all msg is not a TextView, is a EditText

and then we can use addTextChangeListener.

thanks all of you who responds

```
private Button send;
private TextView max;
private EditText msg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     max = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.max);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);

    msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg);
    msg.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            max.setText(String.valueOf(140- (msg.getText().toString().length())));
            if(msg.getText().toString().length()>=140){

                send.setEnabled(false);


            }else
                send.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that onKey is called twice, once for down and one for up.
You can use another method such as onKeyDown:

[onKeyDown documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyDown(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent))

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

Or use a filter using onKey.

Answer (score 0):

`onKey` gets fired twice. Once when the key is pressed  down, and once when it is released.

Or you can try:

1. `onKeyDown()`
2. `onKeyUp()`
3. `KeyEvent.getAction().`

[image]

In this java image, you can see that the person made both a released and a pressed method. This picture is for java, but the concept for android is the same. Use the methods I gave you in that numbered list.

Otherwise, right now, you are listening for two events.

On the right is key pressed, and the left is key released:

[image]

If this was helpful, please mark as best answer. If you need more help, let me know!